# In Spring How to print user first name and last name from "<sec:authentication property="principal.username"/>"

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

How to print user first name and last name from `<sec:authentication property="principal.username"/>`

This `principal.username` only prints user Id. But I want here to print the user first and last name from database. Is it possible?

Comment: You should clarify your question: where do you get the `<sec:authentication property="principal.username"/>`? Which framework are you using? Operating System?

Comment: I am using here Spring Framework.. This is a conept in spring security.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess you are talking about Spring Security.

Here is a solution I used:

Create a class that will map your users. It have to implements the interface *org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails* :

```
public class MyUserDetails implements UserDetails {
    private String username;
    private String password;

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    // Etc.
}
```

Create an implementation of *org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService* that will load your users from the database :

```
@Component
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private MyUserDAO userDAO;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        final MyUserDetails user = userDAO.getUserByUsername(username);
        if(user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user found for username '" + username +"'.");
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

Now you have to tell Spring Security to use your service to load the details from your users :

```
<authentication-manager>
    <user-service id="myUserDetailsService"/>
</authentication-manager>
```

Now you should be able to use `<sec:authentication property="principal.firstname"/>` and `<sec:authentication property="principal.lastname"/>` to display the firstname and the lastname of the current user.

Comment: thanx.. can you tell me about private MyUserDAO userDao;

Comment: It is a class following the [Data Access Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) design pattern. How to create one depends on the API you are using to interact with your database (JDBC, Hibernate, MyBatis, etc.).

Comment: @user2358480 Still stuck ? What do you use to retrieve data from your database ?

Comment: Can you add a snippet using annotation configuration?