# I am using here Struts 2 and Spring Security Integration

Tags: java, struts2, spring-security

In spring security after successfully login how to print user First name and Last name in jsp page like :

sec:authentication property="principal.firstname" and sec:authentication property="principal.lastname"

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Spring How to print user first name and last name from "<sec:authentication property="principal.username"/>"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17297322/in-spring-how-to-print-user-first-name-and-last-name-from-secauthentication-p)

Answer (score 0):

You should implement your own `UserDetails` with properties which you need.

Comment: Thanx Alex.. can u explain me in details, so i can understand clearly . Because i am very new to spring security..

Comment: @user2358480 See similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607696/spring-security-custom-userdetails