# The difference : 'sec:authentication' & 'sec:authentication property'

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have included `<span sec:authentication="name"></span>` in my html page to display the username in my page.

I also find `<span sec:authentication property="principal.username"></span>` to display the same.

All I need is to know is that, is there a difference in the way on how the username is picked from LDAP/DB between these methods? Which method could hold the best response time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Spring How to print user first name and last name from "<sec:authentication property="principal.username"/>"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17297322/in-spring-how-to-print-user-first-name-and-last-name-from-secauthentication-p)

Comment: I did went through that Abdo. I fear this doesn't even explain sec:authentication="name" nor differentiate the workflow & time required to process the name of the user individually by the 2 methods mentioned in this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On typical configurations, i.e. when `UserDetails` interface is used, they are the same.

- The **name** always returns the username on all systems. For configurations with `UserDetails`, it actually translates to *principal.username*.
- The **principal.username** picks the username from the principal object, which is typically a `UserDetails` instance. This property is not guaranteed to exist with all configurations.

Both should be very quick to invoke.